# Tomcat war code visible?

Tags: java, mysql, security, tomcat

I have a war file in which a class calls a MySQL DB from Java and thus has the MySQL login information in plain text in the source code. Obviously, for security resons, I don't want this visible to the outside world. The question is thus if the source code in a war file deployed on Tomcat is visible to the outside world?

Comment: no, the war file is not visible to the outside world

Comment: Use a DataSource configured in Tomcat outside the application. Either admin console or look in Tomcat reference. Though WEB-INF is not visible.

Comment: Why is there source code in your war?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it wont be visible. Provided there is no way to download war- Once war is downloaded- Anyone can locate the class and decompile it to see the password.

Better option would be to configure DataSoure - which is outside of your war.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a problem but not flexible. More usefull to use JNDI. In context.xml put something like this:

```
<Resource
        name="jndi_name_for_datasource"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        testOnReturn="true"
        validationQuery="select 1 from dual"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
        minIdle="1"
        initialSize="1"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
        username="solaris"
        password="super"
        driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
        url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:slife"
    />
```

and use lookup fo JNDI name

Answer (score 1):

But I think it is still a security issue, if anybody else is having access to tomcat server. e.g. other employees or administrators.

I would suggest you to add simple encryption/decryption technique in the code to prevent others to figure out the password.